# Setting up NFS permissions on Synology for Linux (KDE Neon)

Tags: linux, nfs, kde-plasma, synology

I've followed the instructions on the [this Synology article](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/File_Sharing/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_within_the_local_network_NFS) to set up NFS access between my Synology NAS and my Linux (KDE Neon) machine.

If I set the hostname to my local IP it works fine... but the trouble is my local IP changes so I'd need to keep updating the NAS permission settings.

If I use my hostname, let's call it `my-linux-machine` I get the following error:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.11:/volume1/Video
```

Synology support have advised that:

> I've checked the log, and found you've tried to set the client Host name: `my-linux-machine` as you've mentioned.
>
> For your information, this Host name should be a validate Domain name which can be resolved by your NAS's DNS server.
>
> Thus, you'll need to apply a domain name for your Linux (KDE Neon) machine, and a server name is not able to use directly here.
>
> To verify the domain name, you can check it by "Ping" command to your Linux server from your NAS server.
>
> **You may specify a host in three ways:**
>
> - Single host
> - Wildcards: *, *.synology.com
> - Network segment: 203.74.205.32/255.255.255.0, 203.74.205.32/24

Here's where I'm stuck.

Could someone help me understand which of those three options are best suited to my needs?

**Single host:** sounds like the single IP method, or a FQDN which I'm unsure as to what my 'domain' would be if none of it needs to talk to the world wide web.

**Wilcards:** also mentions domain names... again, my setup doesn't need to leave my home network.

**Network segment:** could maybe work? But I'm unsure how to figure what *my* segment would be.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you should be able configure the IP using a mask (based on the answer on the [Synology forum](https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=45304)):

192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0

Hope this helps!